# Calculate the routes from dwg layout

Tags: graph, layout, routes, dwg, wcs

I have a `dwg` 2D layout of a hanging warehouse. We have to development a `WCS` system, this system consist also to calculate the shortest way to reach the destination.

Is there any way to convert the `DWG` to a `GRAPH` and use the `python-networkX` to calculate the route? At the end I have to get a list of track route.

I can find a similar layout in [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=hanging+warehouse+layout&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi70PK7hefxAhWDNuwKHYRICcQQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=hanging+warehouse+layout&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECAAQEzoICAAQCBAeEBNQqeMBWKvpAWC46gFoAHAAeACAAWyIAcEDkgEDNS4xmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=4zHxYPvSGoPtsAeEkaWgDA&bih=1138&biw=2400&hl=it#imgrc=aRrc8_Yep9flIM).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create an application that displays the DWG layout.

The application will respond to mouse movement and clicks on the displayed layout as follows:

- **Left mouse click**: Add a node to the graph  (location or waypoint)
- **Right mouse click on node**: Add single hop link between node and previously selected

Then you can run Dijkstra algorithm whenever you need to calculate the shortest route.

I would NOT recommend using python for this as it is far too slow.